# Can't connect to mongodb on Ubuntu 20.04, connection refused

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

After following the [instructions for installing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) running `mongosh` gives me the following errror:

```
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000 MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by allowing incoming communications on the port 27017, which is the one mongodb uses by default. I did it by using the firewall-configuration gui and adding 27017 as a trusted tcp port but it can be done in [other ways](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/).